# Delete all rows with a specific fill colour across all sheets

Tags: excel, vba

I'm using the following code to try and delete all rows in a whole worksheet that are filled a specific colour:

```
Sub DeleteColourLoop()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rngCl As Range
    Dim xRows As Long
    Dim xCol As Long
    Dim colorLg As Long
    On Error Resume Next
    Set rngCl = Application.InputBox _
        (Prompt:="Select a cell with the background color to be deleted", _
        Title:="Coloured Row Deleter", Type:=8)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If rngCl Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "User cancelled operation." & vbCrLf & _
        "Processing terminated", vbInformation, "Coloured Row Deleter"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    colorLg = rngCl.Interior.Color
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        With ActiveSheet.UsedRange
            For xRows = .Rows.Count To 1 Step -1
                For xCol = 1 To .Columns.Count
                               If .Cells(xRows, xCol).Interior.Color = colorLg Then
                        .Rows(xRows).Delete
                        Exit For
                    End If
                Next xCol
            Next xRows
        End With
    Next ws
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
End Sub
```

This allows me to pick a cell with my desired colour and then hopefully delete all rows of that colour.

However, I am really struggling with getting this to run across all sheets. I've tried multiple methods but they either only affect the current sheet or just crash excel.

I tried using a seperate macro to call upon the original macro for each worksheet as follows:

```
Sub Repeater()
    Dim wkst As Worksheet
 
    For Each wkst In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        Call DeleteColourLoop
 
    Next
End Sub
```

However, this forces me to select a colour on each sheet before it proceeds and takes a very long time. I want to only choose once and then the macro works across all sheets.

Any ideas? Even reworking the macro so that I have to add the RGB value into the macro instead of selecting with a prompt is fine.

Comment: `With ActiveSheet.UsedRange` >> `With ws.UsedRange`

Comment: @TimWilliams Can't believe I missed that, thank you. However - now Excel is bringing up a prompt to confirm "Delete this row?" for each row deleted which the macro didn't used to do. Any idea how I can skip this without an autoclicker?

One more thing - the code is leaving a blank red row at the end of some sheets. Is this to do with the looping?

Comment: Huh - I've never seen a confirmation prompt for deleting a row...  As for the blank red row - hard to say but make sure your `UsedRange` is covering the range you expect it to - it's not always reliable...

Answer (score 1):

- `With ActiveSheet.UsedRange` your code only delete rows on activesheet, change it to `With ws.UsedRange`
- Interaction with worksheet takes time, deleting rows all at once will imporve efficiency
- Disable `ScreenUpdating` is also helpful

```vb
    Dim desRng As Range
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        Set desRng = Nothing
        With ws.UsedRange
            For xRows = .Rows.Count To 1 Step -1
                For xCol = 1 To .Columns.Count
                    If .Cells(xRows, xCol).Interior.Color = colorLg Then
                        If desRng Is Nothing Then
                            Set desRng = .Cells(xRows, xCol)
                        Else
                            Set desRng = Union(desRng, .Cells(xRows, xCol))
                        End If
                        Exit For
                    End If
                Next xCol
                If Not desRng Is Nothing Then
                    desRng.EntireRow.Delete
                End If
            Next xRows
        End With
    Next ws
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```